# VueJS Template Consider a True || False Statement as False, Why?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

[image]

So what in the world is VueJS thinking? Why a combined condition of `true || false` become `false`???? Is it something I did wrong? Can't think of any

Comment: Your top line of code has a greater than or equals, but your bottom line is just a greater than.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `mySelectedItems.length` was 1 because the `cond 2` checks if `mySelectedItems.length` is `>=` 1 and the second part of the `||` condition checks if `mySelectedItems.length` is `>` 1.

Answer (score 1):

Your array `mySelectedItems.length` contains only 1 element and this is breaking your condition:
[image]